# Letters with apostrophe disappears

Tags: javascript, regex, model-view-controller

Here is my regex for validating a e-mailadress. But it keeps removing letters with a apostrophe. For example (Hélen, becomes Hlen)

```
var firstname = $("#FirstName").val().replace(/å/gi, "a").replace(/ä/gi,"a").replace(/ö/gi, "o").replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '');

var lastname = $("#LastName").val().replace(/å/gi, "a").replace(/ä/gi, "a").replace(/ö/gi, "o").replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '');

$("#Mail").val(firstname + "." + lastname + '@customer.Email');
```

Comment: What is your question, what do you want your regex to do? Removing, replacing or keeping them?

Comment: That's not an apostrophe.

Comment: `[^a-z0-9\s]` matches anything that isn't a letter between `a` and `z` or a number between `0` and `9`, and removes it. This is not the right way to validate an email.

Comment: [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: He is constructing email ids from firstname and lastname. 
The `replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')` is removing your é with "" therefore Hélen becomes Hlen

Comment: Okay how should the Regex look like instead?

Comment: The duplicate question shows you how to do what you want to do - removing accents and keeping the base letter, so the email address is as close to the real name as possible.

Comment: add checks for each of the accented letters as you have done for `å,ä,ö` like `replace(/é/gi,"e")`

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need is actually replace accented char with non accented version.

I found this solution here in SO: [Remove accents/diacritics in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript)

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

With : `replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')` you are replacing anything that isn't a *non-accented letter* , by an empty string. 
That's why it is erased.

For that not to happen, you have to do with "é" the same thing you do with "å" or "ä", replace it with the non accented letter.

For example to replace "é", "è", "ê" and "ë" by e you can use `replace(/[éèêë]/gi, "e")` **before** using `replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')`.

You'll have to do the same with "à" and "ô" etc ...

Comment: Thank u so much! It works now.